# Child view stays visible after setting opacity to 0 in superview

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview, alpha

I'm implementing a tool panel for macOS application, and one of the features is dragging panels to reorder them. In my code dragged panel alpha is set to 0 on drag start, and it's snapshot is dragged with the mouse.

The problem is that setting alpha to 0 on panel view don't affect panel header, it's still visible and displayed above dragged view. Also, problem disappears after reordering views in stack - header becomes invisible too next time I dragging panel.

You can see my problem on this gif:

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/419h1.gif)

This code is used on panel drag start:

```
private func panelDragStarted(_ gr: NSPanGestureRecognizer) {
        draggedRealView = gr.view!.superview!
        draggedFakeView = createFakeView(for: draggedRealView)
        draggedFakeView.frame = NSRect(origin: draggedRealView.frame.origin, size: draggedRealView.frame.size)
        stack.addSubview(draggedFakeView)
        draggedRealView.alphaValue = 0
    }
```

Adding this line at the end solves my problem:
`gr.view!.alphaValue = 0`, but it's not obvious why I should change header alpha manually - it's panel subview and should be affected by setting zero alpha to panel.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between first drag attempt and others was setting *stack.wantsLayer* property to true at stack subviews reordering moment. So I just moved `stack.wantsLayer = true` to initialisation time and now it works fine.